# Vue long press resetting on release

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My goal with this code is to detect a long press being applied to the div element. On clicking the div element after the long press is applied, the long press is reset. The problem I'm encountering is that the long press is being reset as I'm releasing the long press. How do I modify so that, the long press is not reset on release? Thanks.

```
<template>
   
   <div
       @click="resetTimer"
        ref="htmlRefOptions"
        class="app-chat__body__messages__message">

            <AppMessageContent :source="'single_message'" :message="message" />

   </div>     
 </template>

<script setup>
   import AppMessageActions from "../Actions/AppMessageActions.vue";
   import AppMessageContent from "./AppMessageContent.vue";
   import AppMessageReactions from "../Reactions/AppMessageReactions.vue";
   import { useChatMessagesStore } from "../../../../Stores/ChatMessagesStore";
   import { onLongPress } from "@vueuse/core";

   const isMessageLongPressed = ref(false);

   const htmlRef = ref(null);
   const htmlRefOptions = ref(null);

   const longPressed = ref(false);
   function onLongPressCallback(e) {
    console.log("Long press detected in AppSingleMessage!");
    longPressed.value = true;
    handleLongPress();
   }

   function resetTimer() {
     console.log("Long press ended in AppSingleMessage!");
     longPressed.value = false;
   }
   onLongPress(htmlRef, onLongPressCallback);
   onLongPress(htmlRefOptions, onLongPressCallback, { delay: 300 });

   const handleLongPress = () => {
      isMessageLongPressed.value = true;
      // console.log("Long press is being handled");
   };
</script>
```

Comment: "the long press is being reset on reselas" I don't get the problem

Comment: Is there some other way you expect `longPressed` to be set to false?  `@click` activates when the mouse button is released.  the method being called by the event resets `longPressed` to false.  If you don't want that happening, don't call that method and/or remove the `@click`.